# Power BI. Importing table from PDF using sharepoint

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

When importing data from PDF files, is the feature only ever supposed to import data from one PDF file? What should happen if another PDF file with the same table structure is added to the folder? Should PowerBI ever be able to simply import date from the newly added PDF file and append it to the existing data set in powerbi? Or does this only work with Excel files? I've previously managed to get this to work with Excel files, but can't quite get it to work with PDF, and am just wondering what I'm missing. PS. what happens currently is that the content of any new PDF files is merged into the existing powerbi table, which is not what I want (I want it to append). Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think Excel and VBA is a better way to go for something like this.